# Edit 2 label based on their values Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have 2 label that has 2 different text, I need to edit that text using javascript but the problem is that I cannot edit those label since they get created by a library, so the only way to edit them is to edit their value once they get populated.

This is the html:

```
    <div class="DateRangeSelector-item">
      <label>Start Date</label>
      <input type="date" max="2015-09-15">
    </div>
    <div class="DateRangeSelector-item">
      <label>End Date</label>
      <input type="date" max="2015-09-16">
    </div>
```

Is it possible through Javascript to check when the label has value Start Date or End Date and change it as I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Struggling to understand whether you want to change the value of the input fields or the label itself. Assuming it's the input fields, dependant on the label's text:

```
$('.DateRangeSelector-item label').each(function() {

    switch ($(this).html()) {

        case 'Start Date':
            $(this).next('input').val('new start value here');
            break;

        case 'End Date':
            $(this).next('input').val('new end value here');
            break;

        default:
            # do nothing

    }

});
```

It's worth nothing at this point that the above code will only work in your specific HTML structure. If you change the layout/order of your elements, the code may break unless you modify lines 6 and 10.

It may also be worth noting that the elements are created by Javascript, you will need to ensure the above code is called after the code that creates your elements.

If I haven't understood what you're looking to accomplish, let me know and I'll edit my answer.

**edit**

To change the label value, use the following instead:

```
$('.DateRangeSelector-item label').each(function() {

    switch ($(this).html()) {

        case 'Start Date':
            $(this).html('new start label here');
            break;

        case 'End Date':
            $(this).html('new end label here');
            break;

        default:
            # do nothing

    }

});
```

Comment: sorry I know I didn't explain the problem very well :P this is almost what I wanted to achieve, what I need is to change the label value instead of the input

Comment: Thanks, that's what I needed! :)